# Cifar10 dataset, Not able to get 38.6%

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying out an example of Stanford CS class on Classification. I am not able to get 38.6% accuracy for Nearest Neighbors Classifier on the following code.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 8.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = load_CIFAR10('datasets/cifar-10-batches-py') 
Xtr_rows = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 32 * 32 * 3) # Xtr_rows becomes 50000 x 3072
Xte_rows = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 32 * 32 * 3) # Xte_rows becomes 10000 x 3072

class NearestNeighbor(object):
  def __init__(self):
   pass

  def train(self, X, y):
    self.Xtr = X
    self.ytr = y

  def predict(self, X):
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    Ypred = np.zeros(num_test, dtype = self.ytr.dtype)


   for i in range(num_test):
      distances = np.sum(np.abs(self.Xtr - X[i,:]), axis = 1)
      min_index = np.argmin(distances) # get the index with smallest distance
      Ypred[i] = self.ytr[min_index] # predict the label of the nearest example

    return Ypred

nn = NearestNeighbors() 
nn.fit(Xtr_rows, Y_train) 
Yte_predict = nn.fit(Xte_rows) 
print ('accuracy: %f' % ( np.mean(Yte_predict == Y_test) ))
```

nn.**train**(Xtr_rows,Y_train), and Yte_predict = nn.**predict**(Xte_rows), however, it was not able to run as NearestNeighbors has no attribute to "train" and "predict". I am currently working on the code on jupyter notebook.

Comment: There are a few differentce between your code and sklearn's classifier. Sklearn is trained by calling `fit(X, y)`, not with `train`. Your code uses what looks like a Minkowski distance with power parameter of 1, whereas sklearn default to 2. You'll need to set `p=2` and `algorithm='brute'` to get similar results to sklearn. Is that why you expect accuracy to be 38%?

Comment: I tried to change to fit(X, y), however the result was 0.0000